# Pipeline.AsyncInvoke on a Powershell remote Pipeline

Tags: c#, powershell, async-await, powershell-remoting

I'm running remote powershell on Lync / S4f / Exchange servers. Synchronous operations all work fine, but I've hit a roadblock converting things to async.

I managed to make the connection/disconnection async since the RunSpace offers your standard BeginOpen/EndOpen and BeginClose/EndClose operations, but InvokeAsync is of type void.

Here's my code (connectionInfo is WSManConnectionInfo which has the uri set as follows

```
new Uri("https://" + config.Server + "/ocspowershell")
```

And this is the actual remote execution code

```
Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
myRunSpace.Open();
using (Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline())
{
    Command myCommand = new Command("Get-CsArchivingPolicy");
    pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);
    pipeLine.StateChanged += PipeLine_StateChanged;
    waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<Collection<PSObject>>();
    pipeLine.Error.DataReady += Error_DataReady;
    pipeLine.Output.DataReady += Output_DataReady;
    pipeLine.InvokeAsync();
    pipeLine.Input.Close();
    await waiter.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Here's what I'm seeing.. 
If I don't close the input, nothing ever happens, other than the pipeline entering running state.

As soon as I close the input, I do get Error_DataReady with 0 items to be read and EndOfPipeline being true, then I get a Output_DataReady, with EndOfPipeline being true but Count also being 0 (so calling Read on the reader doesn't work).

Then the pipeline enters Completed state. So.. the command runs.. but where's the output?

If I do pipeline.Invoke, I get a nice Collection back with my results.. so I know the command is correct. But I must be missing something regarding the output when running in async mode.

Comment: Exchange `pipeLine.Input.Close();` and `pipeLine.InvokeAsync();`.

Comment: That does the trick.. as far as execution goes. But calling reder.Read(reader.Count= on the PipelineReader<PSObject> that you get from Output_DataReady always throws an exception telling me that the method is not supported (likewise for reader.ReadToEnd).. you wouldn't happen to know how to properly read the results?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an alternative way to do async processing.. one that involves a lot less plumping.

```
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                if (remoteRunspacePool != null)
                    ps.RunspacePool = remoteRunspacePool;
                else
                    ps.Runspace = remoteRunSpace;
                Command myCommand = new Command(getPolicyExtractionCommand(dummy));
                Command myCommand2 = new Command("Select-Object");
                ps.Commands.AddCommand(myCommand);
                var props = new string[] { "Identity", "Description", "Name" };
                myCommand2.Parameters.Add("Property", getPropertiesForPolicies(dummy));
                ps.Commands.AddCommand(myCommand2);

                PSDataCollection<PSObject> execRes = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(beingRes, ps.EndInvoke).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Collection<PSObject> processes = execRes.ReadAll();
            }
```

The idea is to use the PowerShell class, which has your regular old-school async stale Begin and End methods for Invoke. Then using the TAP, you can wrap this into a modern day style asynchronous execution.

If you have a previously established runspace (like in my previous sample), you can assign it to the PowerShell instance. It also works with a RunspacePool (which in term supports IAsyncresult style Open and Close methods). Unfortunately, OpenAsync and CloseAsync on a Runspace are again made of this weird construct where you need to await status changes (wire up StateChanged event, call OpenAsync, wait for error or opened status, then continue execution).

IMHO Microsoft should show a bit more async love to PowerShell.